# PEAR not recognising correct PHP directory

Tags: php, pear, archlinux

I just installed PEAR but it is using an incorrect path for PHP, `/usr/bin/php`, rather than the correct one, `/usr/bin/php74`.

This means it won't run at all, so I can't even run `pear uninstall pear`, because it (like any other pear command) just errors out with `/usr/bin/pear line 28: /usr/bin/php: No such file or directory`

How do I fix this? Can I just `rm -rf /usr/bin/pear` and then reinstall with pacman?

(For reference I am using Arch Linux)

Comment: `set PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=/usr/bin/php74/php.exe`

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's Linux, not Windows. Tried it anyway with the path as `/usr/bin/php74` (php74 itself is a binary, not a directory) but I'm afraid it does nothing!

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this so I took a bit of fun time to play with pear.

So, first I installed it through my favorite - and not deprecated yet - AUR helper.

```
$ my-awesome-helper -S php-pear
```

Then I tried to install `XML_Util` (as an example)

```
# pear install XML_Util
WARNING: channel "pear.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pear channel-update pear.php.net" to update
downloading XML_Util-1.4.5.tgz ...
Starting to download XML_Util-1.4.5.tgz (19,191 bytes)
......done: 19,191 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/XML_Util-1.4.5

# echo $?
0
```

From here, I was sure that it is working so I uninstalled it.

```
# pear uninstall XML_Util
uninstall ok: channel://pear.php.net/XML_Util-1.4.5
```

Now, how can we break it or change the location of the PHP binary?
The way to go is to follow the documentation. For our case, it is located [here](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.config.php).

It first states:

> PEAR has a number of configuration options that you can change. Getting an overview of them is as easy as issuing a
>
> ```
> $ pear config-show
> ```

I did it a bit more precisely:

```
# pear config-show | grep bin
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /usr/bin
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /usr/bin/php
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/bin/gpg
```

Yet another question: How to change the value of `php_bin`?

Let's get back to the documentation. It now states:

> Reading single values is accomplished by using config-get. The following command will show you where all the .php files of your installed pear packages reside.
>
> ```
> $ pear config-get php_dir
> /usr/share/pear
> ```
>
> Changing a value is as easy as retrieving it:
>
> ```
> $ pear config-set preferred_state beta
> config-set succeeded
> ```

Therefore, I changed it to something that is not the PHP binary.

```
# pear config-set php_bin /tmp/my-awesome-bin
config-set succeeded
```

Let's check the change:

```
# pear config-get php_bin
/tmp/my-awesome-bin
```

We are now sure that we changed the PHP binary location.

Let's rerun our first command:

```
# pear install XML_Util
WARNING: channel "pear.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pear channel-update pear.php.net" to update
downloading XML_Util-1.4.5.tgz ...
Starting to download XML_Util-1.4.5.tgz (19,191 bytes)
......done: 19,191 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/XML_Util-1.4.5
```

**It's not broken. Weird !?**

From here, I thought, I did something wrong so I rechecked everything I did and I indeed followed the documentation without success.

---

My last resort is always to look at the file or executable to try to understand its behavior. So I did this time too.

It turns out that pear is a simple Shell script. At the time I'm writing this it (`/usr/bin/pear`) looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# first find which PHP binary to use
if test "x$PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN" != "x"; then
  PHP="$PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN"
else
  if test "/usr/bin/php" = '@'php_bin'@'; then
    PHP=php
  else
    PHP="/usr/bin/php"
  fi
fi

# then look for the right pear include dir
if test "x$PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR" != "x"; then
  INCDIR=$PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR
  INCARG="-d include_path=$PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR"
else
  if test "/usr/share/pear" = '@'php_dir'@'; then
    INCDIR=`dirname $0`
    INCARG=""
  else
    INCDIR="/usr/share/pear"
    INCARG="-d include_path=/usr/share/pear"
  fi
fi

exec $PHP -C -q $INCARG -d date.timezone=UTC -d output_buffering=1 -d variables_order=EGPCS -d open_basedir="" -d safe_mode=0 -d register_argc_argv="On" -d auto_prepend_file="" -d auto_append_file="" $INCDIR/pearcmd.php "$@"
```

Here is the relevant part regarding your question:

```sh
if test "x$PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN" != "x"; then
  PHP="$PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN"
else
  if test "/usr/bin/php" = '@'php_bin'@'; then
    PHP=php
  else
    PHP="/usr/bin/php"
  fi
fi
```

Basically:

1. If the `PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN` environment variable is declared. Use it.
2. Otherwise, if the `php_bin` variable (pear config) is set, and is equal to `/usr/bin/php` use `php` as executable.
3. If both (1) and (2) failed; use the `/usr/bin/php` binary as executable.

That explains a lot about why it is still working.

So, I tried again to break it again but this time with the `PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN` environment variable.

```sh
# PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=/tmp/my-awesome-bin pear install XML_Util
/usr/bin/pear: Zeile 28: /tmp/my-awesome-bin: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

This time I have the same error like the one you posted. Meaning that I could break pear and reproduce your issue.

---

Now the solution-s to your problem after understanding what is happening:

1. You can manually run `export PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=/usr/bin/php74` before running `pear`. This solution is temporary and user-wide.
2. You can put the `export PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=/usr/bin/php74` line into your `~/.bashrc` file. This solution is persistent and user-wide.
3. You can put the `PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=/usr/bin/php74`  line into your `/etc/environment` file. This solution is persistent and system-wide.
4. You can put the `export PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=/usr/bin/php74` line into `/etc/profile.d/my_php_pear_solution.sh` file. This solution is persistent and system-wide.
5. You can create a `/usr/local/bin/my-pear` (assuming that `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`) which handles this; given it one of - or all - the 3 executable bit and finally use the `my-pear` CLI instead of the official `pear` one. This solution is persistent and system-wide.

   ```sh
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   # Set the location of our PHP binary.
   export PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=/usr/bin/php74

   # Start pear.
   /usr/bin/pear ${@}
   ```

All of those may work. It's just a matter of scope, usability, and permission - somehow.

I hope this helps. Don't be afraid to ask if something is not clear.

P.S.: Welcome around here :-)